# Almofire with URLRequest with parameter

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am using Almofire in my Application. how do i use dictionary while using `.get` method. My code is as below:

```
func validMemberId(completion: @escaping CompletionHandler){
    guard let cookie = self.cookies else {
        return
    }
    let isRegisterMemberUrl = createUrl(with: checkRegisterMemberIdUrl)

    var isRegisterMemberRequest = URLRequest(url: isRegisterMemberUrl)
    isRegisterMemberRequest.httpMethod = HTTPMethod.get.rawValue
    isRegisterMemberRequest.allHTTPHeaderFields = HTTPCookie.requestHeaderFields(with: cookie)
    Alamofire.request(isRegisterMemberRequest).responseString { (response) in
        { (response) in
            if response.result.isSuccess && response.response?.statusCode == 200 {
            }
        }
}
```

i want to pass this dictionary using Get method along with `URLRequest` , My dictionary  `[String: Any] = ["ID": "001110"]`

Answer (score 0):

Parameters should be a `Dictionary` (key, value)

For get request you don't need to set the method

```
let parameters: Parameters = ["foo": "bar"]

Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/get", parameters: parameters) // encoding defaults to `URLEncoding.default`
```

If you want to make a `post` request you just need to add the `method`

```
let parameters: Parameters = ["foo": "bar"]

Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/post", method: .post, parameters: parameters)
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Manual Parameter Encoding of a URLRequest](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#manual-parameter-encoding-of-a-urlrequest)**

The `ParameterEncoding` APIs can be used outside of making network requests.

```
let url = URL(string: "https://httpbin.org/get")!
var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)

let parameters: Parameters = ["foo": "bar"]
let encodedURLRequest = try URLEncoding.queryString.encode(urlRequest, with: parameters)

Alamofire.request(encodedURLRequest)
```